# set the value of sql data source parameter

Tags: asp.net

I am filtering the data of an SQL data source by setting a `WHERE` clause parameter in this formatting `[@a]` and in the event of a combo box, I would to set the value to this parameter, the previous sql  data source for a gridview

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["@a"].DefaultValue = cid.ToString();
SqlDataSource2.DataBind();
```

I need to pass value to the `WHERE` parameter.

I choose the filtering parsed on non choice ( not form or control or profile or session ...)

This way gives me an error.
Is there any way to give a value for this parameter `[@a]`?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

### **ASPX:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommandType="Text"
                   SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a=@a"  
                   CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"> 
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="a" QueryStringField="a" 
                           DbType="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
              </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

### **C# Code-Behind:**

**change** **`@a`** to **`a`**:

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["a"].DefaultValue = cid.ToString();
SqlDataSource2.DataBind();
```

If **`@a`** is the **FIRST** parameter you can also set it using **`INDEX 0`**:

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = cid.ToString();
SqlDataSource2.DataBind();
```